# How to write dynamic SQL for following?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

1) I have string like this:

```
vagalla AND suresh NOT employee OR industry
```

I want result like:

```
Name like '%vagalla%' and Name like '%suresh%' and not (Name like '%employee%' or description like '%industry4%')
```

2) I have string like this:

```
vagalla OR suresh AND employee OR industry
```

I want result like:

```
(Name like '%vagalla%' or Name like '%suresh%' ) and (Name like '%employee%' or Name like '%industry%')
```

Here Is the function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION DBO.BOOLEANSEARCH(@SEARCHNME VARCHAR(50))                
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)                
AS              
-- SELECT  DBO.GETBOOLEANSEARCH ('VAGALLA SURESH')              
BEGIN               
DECLARE @QRY VARCHAR(MAX)               
DECLARE @SEARCHSTRING VARCHAR(50)               
DECLARE @START INT              
DECLARE @END INT            
SET @SEARCHSTRING = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SEARCHNME,'+' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI,'AND' ),'-' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI,'OR')              
SELECT @START = CHARINDEX('"',@SEARCHSTRING), @END = CHARINDEX('"',REVERSE(@SEARCHSTRING))              
IF( @START = 1 AND @END = 1)                
BEGIN               
     SELECT @QRY =' COLUMNNAME = '+ SUBSTRING(@SEARCHSTRING,2,LEN(@SEARCHSTRING)-2)         
END             
ELSE                
BEGIN               
    IF  (   ((1>(SELECT PATINDEX('% OR %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)))    
            OR (1>(SELECT PATINDEX('% AND %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI))) 
            OR (1>(SELECT PATINDEX('% NOT %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI))) 
            ) AND ((SELECT CHARINDEX('*' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI,@SEARCHSTRING))>1))   
        BEGIN       
            SELECT @QRY= ' COLUMNNAME LIKE '+  REPLACE(@SEARCHSTRING,'*', '%' ) 
        END 
        ELSE IF (   ((1>(SELECT PATINDEX('% OR %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)))    
            OR (1>(SELECT PATINDEX('% AND %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI))) 
            OR (1>(SELECT PATINDEX('% NOT %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI))) 
            ) AND ((SELECT CHARINDEX('*' COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI,@SEARCHSTRING))<1))   
        BEGIN       
            SELECT @QRY= ' COLUMNNAME = ' + @SEARCHSTRING   
        END     
    ELSE            
    BEGIN           
        IF(1<(SELECT PATINDEX('% OR %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)))       
        BEGIN       
            SELECT @QRY =' COLUMNNAME LIKE %'+SUBSTRING(@SEARCHSTRING,1, PATINDEX('% OR %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)-1) +'%' 
                +' OR COLUMNNAME LIKE %'+ SUBSTRING(@SEARCHSTRING, PATINDEX('% OR %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)+3,LEN(@SEARCHSTRING))+'%'
        END     
    ELSE IF(1<(SELECT PATINDEX('% AND %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)))     
        BEGIN       
            SELECT @QRY =' COLUMNNAME LIKE %'+SUBSTRING(@SEARCHSTRING,1, PATINDEX('% AND %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)-1) +'%'    
                +' AND COLUMNNAME LIKE %'+ SUBSTRING(@SEARCHSTRING, PATINDEX('% AND %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)+4,LEN(@SEARCHSTRING))+'%'
        END     
ELSE IF(1<(SELECT PATINDEX('% NOT %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)))     
        BEGIN       
            SELECT @QRY =' COLUMNNAME LIKE %'+SUBSTRING(@SEARCHSTRING,1, PATINDEX('% NOT %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)-1) +'%'    
                +' AND COLUMNNAME NOT LIKE %'+ SUBSTRING(@SEARCHSTRING, PATINDEX('% NOT %', @SEARCHSTRING COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AI)+4,LEN(@SEARCHSTRING))+'%'
        END     
---HERE I NEED TO IMPLEMENT THE OTHER CONDITION
    END         
END             
RETURN @QRY             

END
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried to put together yourself? what were the results? why were the results not satisfactory for you?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you tried. Did you type the above directly into sql-server or is the "string" being used somewhere in code you've written? (if so, please include the code too) What happened when you tried using the "result like" parts in sql-server? did they not give you the results you wanted?

Comment: Question and answer formats are above. requesting to post a result.

Comment: Hello   Taryn East, "vagalla OR suresh AND employee OR industry" is a string I am passing to function. The function needs to return varchar like: (Name like '%vagalla%' or Name like '%suresh%' ) and (Name like '%employee%' or Name like '%industry%')

Comment: Right... so you need to show us the function. What have you written? what language is the function written in? Please edit your question and add any code that you have tried yourself. We are not going to write your function for you - so you need to give it a go, then show us what you've tried (even if it isn't working).

Comment: Note: don't post code in the comments, because the formatting is awful. Please edit your question and put it there...

Answer (score 0):

The precedence of operators is unclear in your example, so I suggest you change the specs to put the parentheses in the input string. If you have a clearly-defined precedence, we could add the parentheses using some code, before processing the next step. Until then, you can use something like this:

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(100)
SET @Input='(vagalla AND suresh) AND NOT (employee OR industry)'
--SET @Input='(vagalla OR suresh) AND (employee OR industry)'

DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Pos INT=0, @Prev INT, @Separator CHAR(1), @Word VARCHAR(100), @Replacement VARCHAR(350)
WHILE 1=1 BEGIN
    SET @Prev=@Pos+1
    DECLARE @Pos1 INT, @Pos2 INT, @Pos3 INT
    SET @Pos1=ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' ',@Input,@Pos+1),0),LEN(@Input)+1)
    SET @Pos2=ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('(',@Input,@Pos+1),0),LEN(@Input)+1)
    SET @Pos3=ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(')',@Input,@Pos+1),0),LEN(@Input)+1)
    SET @Pos=CASE 
        WHEN @Pos1<=@Pos2 AND @Pos1<=@Pos3 THEN @Pos1 
        WHEN @Pos2<=@Pos1 AND @Pos2<=@Pos3 THEN @Pos2
        ELSE @Pos3
    END
    IF @Pos=LEN(@Input)+1 SET @Pos=0
    SET @Separator=SUBSTRING(@Input,NULLIF(@Pos,0),1)
    SET @Word=SUBSTRING(@Input,@Prev,ISNULL(NULLIF(@Pos,0)-1,LEN(@Input))-@Prev+1)
    SET @Replacement=CASE 
        WHEN @Word IN ('AND','NOT','OR','') THEN @Word 
        ELSE 'Name LIKE ''%'+REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Word,'''',''''''),'_','[_]'),'%','[%]')+'%''' 
    END
    SET @Result=ISNULL(@Result,'')+@Replacement+ISNULL(@Separator,'')
    --SELECT @Pos, @Separator, @Word, @Replacement, @Result
    IF @Pos=0 BREAK
END

PRINT 'Input : '+@Input
PRINT 'Result: '+@Result
```

The code searches iteratively for each word, considering the following separators: space, open parenthesis, closing parenthesis. Then replaces each word (except AND, OR and NOT) with the LIKE expression.

When using LIKE with Dynamic SQL, you have to be careful for special characters, like apostrophe, percent and underline. I tried to escape those with REPLACE, but it's important to define the length of the strings properly in this case.